# Editing table's caption's name

Tags: tables, captions

how do I to edit table's caption's name ?

[image]

Transformation : "Table" --->> "Tableau"

Comment: `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}` or use `caption` package.

Comment: With `caption` package, use `\captionsetup[table]{name=Tableau}`

Comment: @HarishKumar, the first wouldn't work. It still "table"

Comment: @HarishKumar, Thanks, I've retained the second proposition.

Comment: Which document class are you using? Are you loading the `babel` package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, report.

Comment: Since I presume you are loading `babel` with the `french` option, you only need to add `\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\tablename{Tableau}}` in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`). There's no need to load an extra package like `caption` just to change the name. Of course, if you were already loading the package, then it is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tableau}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
     \caption{Caption here}\label{tab:mytabh}
     \centering
     Some table comes here
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use simply `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
     \caption{Caption here}
     \centering
     Some table comes here
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```